# Editing google contacts and adding new google contacts through codeigniter application

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

Good Afternoon, I have just created a page which can import google contacts and display them using OAuth2. I have used the google-api-php-client for this. I can successfully get all the contacts' details and display them. However, my main goal is to be able to edit the google contacts' details and add new google contacts from my codeigniter application based on particular user actions. I want to know what functions I need to write and what to do in the corresponding views. Please help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"/>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Google Contacts API</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Google Contacts API v3.0</h2>
<?php
require_once 'lib/google-api-client/autoload.php';
require 'lib/google-api-client/Config.php';
require 'lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php';

$client_id = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.bbbbbb.cccccccccccc.com';
$client_secret = 'e3fsfds4gfg23ha93kmKFkfgK';
$redirect_uri = 'http://ccccccccccccccccccc.com/rddddddddddd/index.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('contact');
$client -> setClientid($client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client -> setScopes('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');
$client -> setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . $redirect_uri);
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    $url = $client->createAuthUrl($_SESSION['token']);
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Import Google Contacts</a>';
}else{
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
        $token->access_token;
        $curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=1000&access_token=" . $token->access_token);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $contacts_json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $contacts = json_decode($contacts_json, true);
        $return = array();
        foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact){
            $return[] = array(
            'name' => $contact['title']['$t'],
            'email' => isset($contact['gd$email'][0]['address']) ? $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'] : false,
            'phone' => isset($contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']) ? $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'] :false,
            );
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($return);
        echo "</pre>";
    }       
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Please feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a contact, first retrieve the contact entry (which you have already done), modify the data and send an authorized PUT request to the contact's edit URL with the modified contact entry in the body.

URL: `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/full/{contactId}`

To create a new contact, send an authorized POST request to the user's contacts feed URL with contact data in the body.

URL: `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full`

Comment: [Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334933/muhammad-sumon-molla-selim) - so what functions do I have to put in the models

Comment: [Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334933/muhammad-sumon-molla-selim) - I have a booking page with a bootbox dialog page and the user can enter new customer data and save it, I also need to check whether that Google Contact already exists - each time as the user may enter an existing customer - also there is a customer page in which current customer details can be edited through a bootbox dialog box and saved - and the changes need to be  reflected in the google contacts - thank you

Comment: [Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334933/muhammad-sumon-molla-selim) - I have views, models and controllers as normal - please give me the direction - thank you

Comment: Can you share your codes please? That would help me to guide you in right way.

Comment: [Muhammad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334933/muhammad-sumon-molla-selim) -ok

Comment: [Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334933/muhammad-sumon-molla-selim) : I have a link here : http://pastebin.com/g3r0sa7E

Comment: [Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334933/muhammad-sumon-molla-selim) - How to put $putname and $newphone as the name and the phone and for the id in $storeid and how to send this data to be updated in google contacts